# PyInstaller 3.3.dev0+1804636 does not exclude source code in exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

i just compiled my main.py using PyInstaller 3.3.dev0+1804636 and Python 2.7.10 and i realised that the .py is included in the .exe. How do i tell PyInstaller to exclude the .py files and only use the .pyc ? It seems to me that PyInstaller needs the .py to look for dependencies, etc. but it somehow includes the .py together with the .exe even though the PyInstaller documentation says that it hides Source Code from the bundle.